# Linq does not see Count column from a group by stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, linq, model-view-controller

I'm trying to get data from a stored procedure with Linq.
Here is the stored procedure:

```
select Statii.Nume_statie, Statii.OraTesa,
count(Distinct Users.Nume) as NrPersoane
from Statii, Users
where Statii.Traseu_ID = @traseu_id and Statii.Station_ID=Users.Station_ID
group by Statii.Nume_statie, Statii.OraTesa
```

and the C# code :

```
 using (LinQDBDataContext r = new LinQDBDataContext())
            {
                var data = r.StatiiDB_allhours_TESA(id_traseu).ToList();

                //ViewBag.IPTable = data;
                return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

The problem is that the `data` variable does not contain the count column of the returned sql (NrPersoane), so in the HTML is shown as undefined.
If i try to execute the stored procedure from **Data connection** is working fine (NrPersoane column is shown).

Does anybody have an idea why?

Comment: Without seeing the code for the `StatiiDB_allhours_TESA` method, it will be hard to diagnose why the column isn't being returned.

Comment: @virusstorm The code for is : USE [TransportManagement]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[StatiiDB_allhours_TESA]
 @ traseu_id int
AS
BEGIN
 select Statii.Nume_statie, Statii.OraTesa,
 count(Distinct Users.Nume) as NrPersoane
 from Statii, Users
 where Statii.Traseu_ID = @ traseu_id and Statii.Station_ID=Users.Station_ID
 group by Statii.Nume_statie, Statii.OraTesa
END

Comment: I get that is the SQL, but there are many ways to call a stored procedure. Without seeing how you are doing it, it will be hard to tell what the issue is. Off the top of my head I'd guess your target entity doesn't have the field you are looking for.